# Spying on a non-exported node.js function using jest not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to mock a non-exported function via 'jest' and 're-wire'.

Here I am trying to mock 'iAmBatman' (no-pun-intended) but it is not exported.

So I use rewire, which does it job well.
But jest.mock doesn't work as expected.

Am I missing something here or Is there an easy way to achieve the same ?

The error message given by jest is :

`Cannot spy the property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

`service.js`

```
function iAmBatman() {
    return "Its not who I am underneath";
}

function makeACall() {
    service.someServiceCall(req => {
        iAmBatman();
    });
    return "response";
}

module.export = {
    makeACall : makeACall;
}
```

`jest.js`

```
const services = require('./service');
const rewire = require('rewire');
const app = rewire('./service');
const generateDeepVoice = app.__get__('iAmBatman'); 

const mockDeepVoice = jest.spyOn(services, generateDeepVoice);

mockDeepVoice.mockImplementation(_ => {
    return "But what I do that defines me";
});

describe(`....', () => {
    test('....', done => {
        services.makeACall(response, () => {

        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 7):

It is not entirely clear what your goal is, but if you look at the [documentation of jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname), you see that it takes a `methodName` as the second argument, not the method itself:

```
jest.spyOn(object, methodName)
```

This explains your error: you didn't give the function *name*, but the function itself.
In this case, using `jest.spyOn(services, 'iAmBatman')` wouldn't work, since `iAmBatman` is not exported, and therefore `services.iAmBatman` is not defined.

Luckily, you don't need `spyOn`, as you can simply make a new mock function, and then inject that with rewire's `__set__` as follows:

(note that I deleted the undefined `service.someServiceCall` in your first file, and fixed some typos and redundant imports)

```js
// service.js

function iAmBatman() {
    return "Its not who I am underneath";
}

function makeACall() {
    return iAmBatman();
}

module.exports = {
    makeACall: makeACall
}
```

```js
// service.test.js

const rewire = require('rewire');
const service = rewire('./service.js');

const mockDeepVoice = jest.fn(() => "But what I do that defines me")
service.__set__('iAmBatman', mockDeepVoice)

describe('service.js', () => {
    test('makeACall should call iAmBatman', () => {
        service.makeACall();
        expect(mockDeepVoice).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
})
```

---

Another option would be to restructure your code with `iAmBatman` in a seperate module, and then mock the module import with Jest. See [documentation of `jest.mock`.](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)